# How can I open a new document without saving the current document by using a single command in Vim

Tags: vim, command-line

In Vim

`:w` saves the document `document1`

`:wq` or `:x` quits the document `document1` after saving

`wq!` quits the document `document1` without saving

`:sav document2` or `:w` + `:e document2` saves the document `document1` and opens the document `document2`

What I want is that I want to open a a new document `document2` without saving the document `document1`, and I want to do so using a single command.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want

```
:e! document2
```

to edit document2, discarding all changes to the current buffer.

Comment: `set hidden` to allow Vim to "hide" unsaved buffers when abandoned.

Comment: If you just want to discard current buffer allowing you to give it another name you can do: `:bd!`. Which means buffer delete.